# IPP Customer Account Data API com.intuit.ipp.aggcat.exception.InvalidRequestException: 403 : Forbidden

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, customer-account-data-api

I have a test that makes a call and gets the accountList. I used the institution id 100000 (testing id) with id direct and password anyvalue with userId nfarooqui. I got the response the first time, it returned with 10 accounts. the second time I changed the userId to changeit and gave the same credentials this time it returned with 403 error. Now even when I am using my previous userId it keep throwing same exception.
Secondly I read in documentation that for testing purpose we can only have 5 userids and 10 accounts. I am wondering if the institutionid 100000 and with test credentials have 10 accounts associated with them; we can never have more than one userid? I am not sure how 5 userids can be tested with. Thanks in advance!

Comment: 403 generally means userid/pwd error.

Answer (score 0):

In CAD API, in dev mode the number of customer/account restrictions is changed.You can create  maximum of 20 users and 10 accounts per user.

Ref - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0020_customeraccountdata/faq#How_many_distinct_customers_can_be_created_while_in_development_mode.3F

To resolve this 403 issue, you can either call deleteUser or you can delete([DeleteAccount API](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0020_customeraccountdata/customer_account_data_api/0020_api_documentation/0080_deleteaccount)) individual accounts which are already added to your profile.

Thanks